# Interpreting coefficients of beta regression

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, beta-distribution, beta-regression

I have implemented a beta regression and am a little confused on how I should interpret the coefficients of my model. For context, both my independent variables and dependent variable are expressed in percentage form, ranging from [0, 1]. The only exception is one independent variable which takes the binary value of 0 or 1. Does anybody mind sharing how I could interpret the coefficients here in this beta regression? I've never worked with a dataset like this before; any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What link function did you use?

Comment: @shadowtalker I used a logit link